# NSMutableDictionary contents inconsistent with output of allValues

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmutabledictionary

So long story short, there's a discrepancy between the output of a `NSMutableDictionary`'s contents and the result of calling `allValues` on the same object. Below is some debugger output after inspecting the object which demonstrates my problem: (made generic of course)

```
(lldb) po self.someDict.allKeys
<__NSArrayI 0xa5a2e00>(
    <SomeObject: 0xa5a2dc0>,
    <SomeObject: 0xa5a2de0>
)

(lldb) po self.someDict.allValues
<__NSArrayI 0xa895ca0>(
    0.5,
    0.5
)

(lldb) po self.someDict
{
    "<SomeObject: 0xa5a2dc0>" = (null);
    "<SomeObject: 0xa5a2de0>" = (null);
}
```

So as we can see, the actual output of the `NSMutableDictionary` contains null values for both its entries, but the contents of `.allValues` contains the proper data. These three outputs were taken at the same time in execution.

I'm not sure why this is happening, but I think it may have something to do with the fact that I'm encoding/decoding the object which this dictionary is a property of using `CoreData`. I believe I'm doing this properly:

```
[aCoder encodeObject:self.someDict forKey:@"someDict"];
```

and to decode

```
self.someDict = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"someDict"];
```

The weird thing is that if I inspect the dictionary before it ever gets encoded, it is still in the state described at the beginning of the post, so this is why I'm doubtful the `CoreData` actions are screwing with the contents.

As always, please don't hesitate to request additional information.

**EDIT:** The problem was as answered below. I was using a custom class which didn't cooperate with isEqual, so my solution was to change the storage and structure of my logic, which made using a Dictionary unnecessary.

Comment: What is the type of the values? Can you show us the construction of a dictionary? I feel you've probably edited out the problem in making it generic.

Comment: The types of the keys are custom classes which implement the NSCoding protocol correctly, and the values are CGFloat.

Comment: `CGFloat` is not a class and cannot be used as a value in a dictionary.  Please be more specific.

Comment: My apoologies, I meant NSNumber, initialized from a CGFloat.

Comment: I've seen this sort of weirdness when reference counting got hosed and objects in the dictionary got released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not been able to duplicate the problem using `NSString` as keys and `NSNumber` as values.  I suspect that your custom class does not properly implement `hash` and/or `isEqual`. Specifically, the results from those two methods must be consistent, meaning that if `isEqual` returns true, then the `hash` values for the two objects must be identical.

You also need to ensure that your class implements `NSCopying` properly and that a copy is equal to the original.

Comment: Thanks for this, I didn't realize this. I'll investigate and get back to you.

Comment: You also need to ensure that your class implements `NSCopying` properly and that a copy is equal to the original.

Comment: This is the problem. I changed how my program works and no longer need to use a dictionary. I'll keep this in mind in the future though.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule, don't use custom objects for dictionary keys. Just use strings and be done with it.

As user3386109 points out, custom objects must properly implement the `-hash` and `-isEqual` methods in order to be used as dictionary keys, and even then, custom objects don't work correctly for dictionary keys for things like key/value coding.

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the problem. I'm not sure why I thought it would be a good idea to use my custom classes as the keys.